# Find $f$ such that $5f(-x)+f(1-x)=2x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f$ be the function defined on the real line by:
>   $$5f(-x)+f(1-x)=2x$$
>    - Find an expression for $f(x)$ in terms of $x$

My Thoughts:

I tired first to check whether $f$ is even, odd, or neither.which could help me to find the right expression of $f$

\begin{aligned}
5f(x)+f(1+x)&=-2x\\
5f(-x)+f(1-x)&=2x
\end{aligned}
$$5(f(x)+f(-x))+f(1-x)+f(1+x)=0 $$
But with no luck

- **I'm interested in more ways of finding answers**

Comment: @user300 i got this $5f(x-\frac{1}{2})+f(\frac{1}{2}+x)=1-2x$

Comment: Hint: consider linear functions.

Comment: @DavidSchneider-Joseph this notion not authorized for this level of course

Comment: You can restate @DavidSchneider-Joseph's suggestion like this: Consider functions of the form $f(x)=ax+b$...

Comment: where is my comment? :'(

Comment: I hope you realize that there are infinitely many answers to your question. The comments of sranthrop and DavidSchneider-Joseph are excellent and help you to find one answer, the simplest, but there are others. Your given equation implies that if you know $f(x)$ for a given $x$ then you can find $f(x+n)$ for that $x$ and any integer $n$, but you cannot find it for any other parameter.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I'm interested in more ways of finding answers

Answer (score 1):

For every $u \in [0,1)$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, define

$$ {}_ug_{n} = f(n + u) $$

Then, for every $u \in [0,1)$, ${}_ug$ is a sequence satisfying the recurrence relation

- $ 5{}_u g_n + {}_u g_{n+1} = -2(u+n) $
- ${}_u g_0 = f(u) $

From there, it's easy to run this in reverse:

- For every $u \in [0,1)$, pick any real number value for ${}_u g_0$
- Let ${}_ug_n$ be the solution to the recurrence relation $ 5{}_u g_n + {}_u g_{n+1} = -2(u+n) $
- Define $$f(x) = {}_{\{x\}}g_{\lfloor x \rfloor}$$

where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

Then this function $f$ satisfies the relation in the OP.